# Integrating JQuery into a CMS controlled environment HTML/CSS/PHP on XAMPP server

Tags: php, jquery, sql

I'm having a hard time adding dynamic functionality to my website with JQuery.

```
<table id="structure">
    <tr>
        <td id="navigation">
            <?php echo public_navigation($sel_subject, $sel_page); ?>
        </td>
        <td id="page">
            <?php if ($sel_page) { ?>
                <h2><?php echo htmlentities($sel_page['menu_name']); ?>   </h2>
                <div class="page-content">
                    <?php echo strip_tags(nl2br($sel_page['content']), "<b><br><p><a>"); ?>
                </div>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <h2>Welcome to my "to the point" news and blog mix.</h2>
            <?php } ?>
           <br />
           <?php
           // garbledeegoo starts here
           ?>
           <p>JScript Practice</p>
           <div id="jscriptprac">text</div>
           <br /> 
           <h2>To Do</h2>
        <form name="checkListForm">
            <input type="text" name="checkListItem"/>
        </form>
        <div id="button">Add!</div>
        <br/>
        <div class="list"></div>
           <?php
           // garbledeegoo ends here
           ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

the problem is i cant make jquery tag selectors style my navigation where i have SQL statements that retrieve my content.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("*").hover(function(){
    $(this).stop(true, true).animate({ width:"+=25px", padding:"+=25px" });
}, function() {
    $(this).stop(true, true).animate({ width:"-=25px", width:"-=25px" });
});
});
```

this is just selecting eveything but it still doesnt select the nav.

```
<td id="navigation">
    <?php echo public_navigation($sel_subject, $sel_page); ?>
</td>
```

I'd like to add .animate jquery to the subjects and pages which are displayed like a list as a side navbar. is there a way to style a query result?

I apologize for my lack of accurate vocabulary. codeybuzz.com is the website if you are having trouble visualizing what I mean, Instead of changing the color of my nav links on a .hover event, i want to animate them on mouseover with jquery. I think doing it with tables might have something to do with it not being selectable, but I dont know how to change them all to divs and not wreck my css styling that i already have in place.

this is the HTML rendered

```
<td id="navigation"> 
 <ul class="subjects">
  <li><a href="index.php?subj=1">About Codey Buzz</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.php?subj=2">No Rubbish, Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.php?subj=3">Top News</a></li>
 </ul>   
</td>
```

I achieved some kind of effect with this, but it isn't very effective.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("ul.subjects > li").hover(function(){
    $(this).mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).animate({ width: "+=50px" }).stop(true, true);
    });
    $(this).mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).animate({ width: "-=50px" }).stop(true, true);
});
});
});
```

Comment: jQuery selectors will target your _rendered_ HTML content.  It can't see your PHP.   Keep that in mind when writing your jQuery.

Comment: please show us the html-rendered version of <td id="navigation">
    <?php echo public_navigation($sel_subject, $sel_page); ?>
</td>

Comment: I added the rendered HTML to the end of my original post. I didn't try selecting it like that.

Comment: Why not just render the page without JQuery added and then view page source. You can use this for your JQuery selectors